# Не добавляется запись нового юзера в бд с помощью jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Не работает часть проекта которая касается Spring security, когда я регистрирую нового пользевателя, то оно сохраняет его в бд,но вот одна проблемка, метод save() почему-то не работает. Вся проблема именно в том методе которые сохраняет пользевателя, а он находится в spring.site.service.UserServiceImpl.save(). Вариант сменить метод userDao.save() на saveAndFlash() не работает. Помогите мне разобраться почему jpa не хочет регистрировать пользаветелей. Вроде и конфигурацию правильную сделал и аннотации также подобовлял, но все равно никакого результата .Также если надо что-то уточнить, спрашивайте, с радостью отвечу.

Технологии которые я юзал: Spring Security|MVC, Hibernate, Postgresql, Maven, JSP
Ссылка на [гит](https://github.com/Dimassss/SpringSite/tree/my_site) если нужно узнать подробности

Интерфейс который работает через jpa

```
package spring.site.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import spring.site.model.User;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Класс с методом save()

```
package spring.site.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import spring.site.dao.RoleDao;
import spring.site.dao.UserDao;
import spring.site.model.Role;
import spring.site.model.User;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Set<Role> roles=new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(roleDao.getOne(1L));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDao.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Настройки хибернейта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="source">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring_site"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="karpus2001"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="source"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>spring.site.model.Product</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Beans-->

    <bean class="spring.site.dao.ProductDaoImpl" id="productDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="spring.site.service.ServiceImpl" id="service">
        <property name="productDao" ref="productDao"/>
    </bean>

    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="spring.site"/>-->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <!--<mvc:annotation-driven/>-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

Настроки jpa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!--<property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>-->

        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring_site"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="karpus2001"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="spring.site.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>



    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="spring.site.dao"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: надо было исправить предыдущий вопрос, а не создавать новый. призапуске приложение у вас есть какие-нибудь ошибки?

Comment: никаких ошибок при запуске нету, но выскакивает когда я пытаюсь зарегистрировать пользевателся. Вот правда этот эксепшин обманчивый, на самом деле он возникает именно по той причине которою я вам показал. Эксепшин бросается налл на 29 строку класса spring.site.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl

Comment: Ксати я создал новый вопрос заново потому что если бы этого не сделал на мой вопрос никто бі не ответил, уже проверено))

Comment: Насчет проекта, перед тем как создать этот проект я создал по отдельности секурити и крад часть проекта и они работали идеально и без багов всяких и при слиянии вот такое получилось, Кстати эти проекты у меня хранятся в репозитории в виде веток security и crud, но сливал я это в ручную а не с помощью гита

Comment: не отвечаю не потому, что вопрос старый, а потому, что он не очень качественный. вы можете улучшить качество добавив [mcve]. я попробовал запустить ваше приложение и у меня есть ошибки при старте.

Comment: У меня ошибок при старте нету, но при попытки зарегистрироваться есть

Comment: потому что у нас разные окружения, так как не все настройки описаны в самом проекте.

Answer (score 0):

Юзера не регистрировало потому что у меня было 2 разных менеджера, jpa и hibernate, и обое они имели одинаковые айди и также поскольку менеджера было двое нужно было указать какой методу менеджер подавать через анотацию @Transactional